# Determine if this set a group

Tags: group-theory

I need to determine whether or not this group is a set

"The set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself, under the composition of functions"

I don't fully understand the problem. What exactly are all of the functions  from $\{1,2,3\}$? And what do they mean by being under composition of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this function $f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 3$, this is an example of the set of all functions of the set $S = \{1,2,3\}$ to itself. You can denote all of them using the following notation

$$
f: \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3)
\end{array}\right)
$$

Here's an sketch of the proof, you can fill in the missing pieces. Remember that in order to form a group you need to define a binary operation, in this case is the composition. So, if you have a function $f$ and a function $g$, $f\circ g$ means

$$
f \circ g: \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3)
\end{array}\right) \circ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
g(1) & g(2) & g(3)
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
f(g(1)) & f(g(2)) & f(g(3))
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now that we defined the set of elements $F = \{f: S \to S\}$ and the operation ($\circ$), these are the things we requiere for $(F,\circ)$ to form a group

- *Closure*: For each $f, g \in F$ then $f\circ g$ must be an element of $F$. This one is immediately satisfied, since the result of applying $g$ on $S$ is again $S$, so when applying $f(g(S))$ we obtain again $S$, and consequently $f\circ g$ is a function of $S$ to $S$, that is $f\circ g\in F$
- *Associativity*: $f\circ(g\circ h) = (f\circ g) \circ h$
- *Identity element*: Of course this element exist in $F$

$$
e: \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right)
$$

- *Inverse element*: For each $f\in F$ we require the existence of an element, denoted by $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}\circ f = f\circ f^{-1} = e$. This actually constrains the set of all possible functions $F$, indeed, they must be function 1-to-1 and onto, which ultimately translates into the fact that if $f$ is such that

$$
f: \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3)
\end{array}\right)
$$

then the bottom row has to be a permutation of of the upper row. If this the case, the inverse can be defined.

You can check that the size of all functions in $F$ satisfying these properties is 6. And the group is call the Symmetric Group of order 3: [$S(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)

Answer (score 2):

You missed some information in the question. It is all the functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ **to itself**, i.e. the set $F =\{f: \{1,2,3\} \mapsto \{1,2,3\}\}$

And composition of function is the operation we define on $F$, i.e. $f \in F$, and $g \in F$, the operation of $f \circ g$ is composition of the two functions.

Comment: @Allan The function $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 1$ has no inverse. If I give you $1$ and ask you "what one input did I have to feed into $f$ to get this $1$?" and you can't give me an answer  because three different inputs gave me the same output. So an inverse function saying $f^{-1}(1) = 1,2,3$ isn't a function at all, as a function can't output multiple items for single inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself. These are the assignments of $1$, $2$ and $3$ each to one of $1$, $2$ and $3$. For example, $f(1) = 2$,$f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 2$ defines a function in $S$.

You may enjoy drawing this graphically, with three dots to represent the domain, and another three dots to represent the range, and arrows indicating what elements are sent where.

"Under composition of functions" means that the binary operation on $S$, $m: S \times S \to S$, is the function $f \circ g$ from $S \times S \to S$. If we compose two functions from $S$ to $S$, we get another function from $S$ to itself.

You would need to check the group axioms. What is the identity? Does every element have an inverse?

Comment: What would be an example of a function that didn't have an inverse?

Comment: @Allan That is your homework ... there are not that many of them, so try writing some down. As a notational shorthand, I suggest using the dot picture. Having an inverse means that the function can be undone by another function.

Comment: I am not required to produce an example, I know the answer is that not all functions have an inverse. The reason I'm asking is because I'm still not too sure about the question, so an example would help

Comment: @Allan Can you give me an example of a function in $S$ without an inverse?

Comment: That's what I'm asking you for 

Comment: @Allan Can you give me an example of a function in $S$ which is not injective?